I overstayed in Israel 2 years ago and now my entry was denied
I'm a US citizen and went to Israel in 2022. I had a visa for 90 days, but due to an emergency, I actually stayed 98 days.
In 2024, I tried to go back there, but not by air. I went through Jordan River Border Crossing and they refused my entry. The reason mentioned for denying the entry was "prevention of illegal immigration considerations".
What does it mean and how can I fix it?

@hkotsubo Thanks. I couldn't bear to correct it. Glad you did.

For editors: As a matter of fact, "entry from Jordan" is not the same as "through Jordan River Border Crossing". There are multiple border checkpoints between Jordan and Israel, and one of them (Aqaba - Eilat) involves no Jordan river crossing.

It depends a lot of the "emergency" and how did you notified them when you had such emergency. Else you demonstrated you cannot be trusted, so it may be difficult to get soon an entry. Also you frequency of travel and motivations may affect. Ask embassy, maybe you need a visa (so they can get and evaluate documentation slowly).

@Johnnyjanko You're right, thanks for pointing this out. I've just made an educated guess based on the original text. Abed, could you please confirm which border checkpoint you went?

As with any other country, after a violation of your conditions of entry you're no longer welcome. In order to be able to visit Israel, you'll need to apply for a visa before you travel. If you're a US citizen, the airlines might let you board without knowing you'd be denied entry given that the US citizens don't generally need a visa to Israel. You'd still be denied entry.
You can also apply for a ETA-IL (Israeli version of ESTA), which is currently in public pilot, and see if you get the approval. It will soon be required, and you won't be allowed to board without it.

i applay for ETA-IL but keep give me a denied

@AbedQab well, here's your answer. If it is really critical - apply for a visa at the nearest consulate, otherwise... have a vacation elsewhere?

In some countries there is a hard and fast rule regarding how long a person is inadmissible after an overstay. Is anyone familiar with the situation in Israel?

I couldn't find anything other than the fact that the Israeli immigration law (1952) actually criminalizes visa overstays. Never heard of anyone actually imprisoned though.

@AbedQab With a denial of entry and ETA-IL refusal on your travel history I doubt you’ll be going to Israel any time soon. If you desperately need/want to go there, apply for a visa and get advice on the application from an Immigration lawyer.
